# Numero mayoritario

Tags: c++

En este ejercicio me piden escribir una `funcion` para saber si un numero es `MAYORITARIO`. O sea si existe un elemento almacenado en el vector que aparece mas de N/2 veces siendo N el numero de elementos del vector

Error en la linea 15

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool mayoritario(float v[],int n);
int n;
float v;
int main()
{

mayoritario(v,n);
cout<<mayoritario(v,n);
return 0;
}

bool mayoritario(float v[],int n){ //Linea 15
    int i,j,nveces,nvmaximo=0;
    for(int i=0 ;i<=n/2 ;i++){
        nveces=1;
        for(int j=i+1 ;j<n ;j++){
            if(v[i]==v[j]){
                nveces++;
            }
            if(nveces>nvmaximo){
                nvmaximo=nveces;
            }
        }
    }
     return (nvmaximo>n/2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que se está presentando es debido a que se está declarando `float v;` (una variable de tipo float) y la función `bool mayoritario(float v[],int n, int num)` está esperando una variable arreglo de float (o puntero a float para ser más preciso).

Para solucionar el problema, se tiene que agregar a la definición de la variable lo siguiente:

`float v[]={0,1,2,2,2,2,0,1,2,2};`

Esto soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 0):

La función mayoritario debería aceptar un parámetro más que es el número que se va a evaluar y se debe recorrer todo el arreglo para realizar las comparaciones. Ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool mayoritario(float [],int n, int num);
int n=10;
float v[10]={3,1,3,1,3,3,1,1,3,3};

int main()
{
    int num=3; //número a evaluar
    cout<<"Evaluando el numero: "<<num;
    cout<<" -> El numero: "<<num;
    if (mayoritario(v,n,num)) cout<<" es MAYORITARIO";
    else cout<<" no es MAYORITARIO";
    return 0;
}

bool mayoritario(float v[],int n, int num){
    int i,nveces=0;
    for(int i=0 ;i<n ;i++){
        if(v[i]==num){
            nveces++;
        }
    }
    if(nveces>n/2)
       return true;
    else
       return false;
}
```

Salida:

```
Evaluando el numero: 3 -> El numero: 3 es MAYORITARIO
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas rápido es usar un mapa para ir contando el número de repeticiones de cada número. Después se recorre ese mapa y se mira si alguna cifra cumple:

```
bool mayoritario(float v[],int n){
  std::map<int,int> totales;
  for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    totales[v[i]]++;

  const int limite_min = n/2;
  for(auto& par: totales) {
    if(par.second>limite_min)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Para hacerlo sin usar contendores, en plan sencillo, son preocuparte demasiado del rendimiento del algoritmo, podrías hacer algo similar así:

```
bool mayoritario(float v[],int n){
  for(int i=0 ;i<n;i++){
    const int valor=v[i];
    int total = 0;
    for( int j=i+1;j<n; j++)
      if( v[j]==valor) total++;

    if( total > n/2 )
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Este último código únicamente intenta ser ilustrativo y admite mucho margen de mejora.

He escrito esto desde el móvil, por lo que no puedo probar si compilan. si hay erratas o no compila avisadme y lo corrijo.

Un saludo.